# How to restrict HTML 5 draggable to be dropped in browser URL bar in chrome

Tags: html, html5-draggable

I am using simple HTML5 draggable for my project. I have noticed few strange behavior. Any text I select at chrome are draggable though there is no draggable property added. These selected text are droppable to any textbox even in browser URL bar and on drop to URL bar it is going out of application and going to search google site.

So how to restrict any draggable element to be dropped at browser URL bar

Comment: It seems to be an OS feature, which many people use.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict this feature?